# Flutter save List with shared preferences

Tags: listview, flutter, sharedpreferences

I try to save a list of strings permanent to the device. When trying to add a List through a pop-up dialog I the following error is displayed

*E/flutter (10074): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.*

*E/flutter (10074): Receiver: null*

*E/flutter (10074): Tried calling: add("drinks")*

Further on the ListView is not displayed when opening the page. (It opens after you enter the on screen dialog)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Categories extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategoriesState createState() => _CategoriesState();
}

class _CategoriesState extends State<Categories> {
  List<String> categoryList = List<String>();
  TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (categoryList == null) {
      setState(() {
        categoryList = ['Food', 'Clothes'];
      });
    }
    _update();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Categories"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: getCategoriesListView(),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _displayDialog(context);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  ListView getCategoriesListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: categoryList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, int position) {
          return Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 2.0,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(categoryList[position]),
              trailing: GestureDetector(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.delete,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _delete(context, categoryList[position]);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  void _add(BuildContext context, String category) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    categoryList.add(category);
    prefs.setStringList('Categories', categoryList);
    showSnackBar(context, 'Your category was added');
  }

  void _delete(BuildContext context, String category) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    categoryList.remove(category);
    prefs.setStringList('Categories', categoryList);
    showSnackBar(context, 'Your category was removed');
  }

  void _update() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    categoryList = prefs.getStringList('Categories');
  }

  void showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message) async {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar((snackBar));
  }

  _displayDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Add new category'),
            content: TextField(
              controller: _textFieldController,
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('ADD'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    String name = _textFieldController.text;
                    print(name);
                    _add(context, name);
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  });
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('CANCEL'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `_update()` method inside `initState()` function rather than `build()`. Right now, every time you call `setState()` the `build()` function is called which in turn calls `update()` due to which the `categoryList` gets overwritten.

Hence you're not able to add new items to the `List`.

You can do something like this -

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _update();
}
```

And then don't call the `_update()` method inside `build()`.
But now since we moved the `_update()` call outside `build()` you will have to use `setState()` inside `_update()` so that the state is refreshed properly.

```
void _update() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  categoryList = prefs.getStringList('Categories');
}
```

Hope this helps!

Also, you shouldn't call `setState()` directly inside the `build()` method, you might get an error, so you can also move the below code inside `initState()`.

```
//Move this inside initState();
if (categoryList == null) {
  setState(() {
    categoryList = ['Food', 'Clothes'];
  });
}
```

The `initState()` method is only call once when initializing your widget before the `build()` method is called.

Comment: I now get the following error when then dialog screen opens


```════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Categories(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#ea957], _InheritedTheme], state: _CategoriesState#df48e):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length```

Comment: Looks like you're calling `_upadte()` after checking that `categoryList` is `null`. You should assign the value from `SharedPreferences` to `categoryList` only if it's not `null`.

Comment: So how do I need arrange this initStat()

1. super.initState()           2. if clause      3. _update()  right?

 ```@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (categoryList == null || categoryList.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        categoryList = ['Food', 'Clothes'];
      });
    }
    _update();
  }```

Comment: Set `categoryList = prefs.getStringList('Categories'); ` inside update only if `categoryList` is `null` or empty.

Comment: in the initState() I add Food and clothes to the list when its empty and then call the `_update()` function and then try to get them saved data but only if its empty. The problem is the list is not empty anymore because I added Food and clothes in the initState()